# Creating primary key on existing table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a table of the following form:

```
   create table tab1(i1 int, i2 character varying);
```

I want to make i1 as the primary key. However my problem is i1 column contains duplicate rows.
In order to achieve this I created a table of the following form:

```
   create table tab2(i1 int, i2 character varying);
insert into tab2 (i1, i2)
(select distinct * from tab1);
 alter table tab2 add primary key(i1);
```

After doing so I get the following error:

```
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "tab2_pkey" for table "tab2"
ERROR:  could not create unique index "tab2_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (i1)=(1958) is duplicated.
```

Can someone please help me create primary key on tab2?

Comment: `could not create unique index "tab2_pkey"` and `create primary key on tab1?`. which table you mean? 1 or 2?

Comment: @Mark Actually it does not matter to me whether i use tab1 or tab2. Actually both tables are the same. Creating primary key on either of them will solve my purpose.

Comment: Can you make the table with http://sqlfiddle.com  and past the link. So we can check the error.

Comment: Have you checked whether your select statement (select distinct * from tab1) is having any duplicates. Especially for id 1958?

Answer (score 1):

```
Key (i1)=(1958) is duplicated.
```

Please run select

```
select distinct * from tab1 where i1 = 1958
```

and make sure that will return multiple rows in result. 
For examle, rows

```
 | i1   |  i2 | 
 | 1958 | '1' |
 | 1958 | '2' |
```

is different and distinct return 2 rows. If you really need a primary key on the i1, you must provide unique values ​​are inserted. Try this:

```
insert into tab2 (i1, i2) (select i1, max(i2) from tab1 group by i1);
```

Instead of function max() you can use any aggregating.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple records with the same primary key i1 and different values in i2, because the primary key is supposed to uniquely identify the records.

In your case, what record is identified by i1= 1958 ?

If all i2 values are the same for a given i1, you have duplicate records and you have to remove them before creating the primary key on i1, if some i2 values are different for a given i1 value, you have to choose another primary key (for example add an identity column and make the primary key on this column).